# Link2sd not working properly

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, link2sd

I've a Samsung Galaxy Ace and recently I installed link2sd, created the partiotion and everything it needs. It works. But I'm having two issues. The first one: each time I turn on the phone I get a notification from link2sd, I open it and a message says the following (translated by me, so it is not the exact text):

> Mount warning
>
> The 2nd partition wasn't mounted during the start, it was mounted after the system finished starting. With that reason your linked apps aren't visible for the system right now. To make them available again, please try "Quick restart".

The buttons are: "Quick restart" and "Cancel". After I make a quick restart all apps work good.

The second problem its that the launcher (not the default one) can't load widget. At the beggining I thought this one was easy: I unlinked the launcher and the apps which made widgets. But nothing, still can't be loaded.

*Note* killink the launcher and starting it again doesn't solve the problem

Please any help, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stock Samsung software always mounts the SD card after the system is up, at least on my Vibrant, so I would expect there's not too much you can do about that without hacking the startup scripts (presumably difficult).

As for the second problem, the Market description says: "It can break some apps if they are not meant to be moved to the SD card (Such as Widgets)."  Try moving any widgets back to your phone storage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! About the first problem isn't there absolutly anything I can do? (beside hacking the scripts where I have zero chances). I used to have a Galaxy I551 and it worked fine. About the second problem I have already unlinked and moved them to the internal storage.. but nothing.

Comment: @Diego Hmm, if it worked on the i551 I would assume link2sd *should* have set up early mounting for you, maybe it just doesn't work right on your device ... I'd suggest contacting the developer.

Comment: Here @roxan has already contacted him, sadly it doesn't seem to be a link2sd issue. What can I do about the widgets?

Comment: The widget problems were solved "magically"

Answer (score 2):

I've HTC Desire and faced similar problem having to quick reboot. I emailed the developer for which he said:

> Some roms like new Samsung GB roms do not have install-recovery.sh and
>   init.d scripts to mount 2nd partition at boot. Therefore Link2SD
>   mounts the 2nd partition after system finishes mounting and you need
>   to perform "Quick reboot" in order to see linked apps..

Comment: In resume, there's nothing I can do but quick rebooting each time I turn on the phone?

Comment: That's what the developer himself said :)